# popup in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla, popup

In my site I have a pop-up for displaying the 'Edit User Info page'. I have created the pop-up using Rokbox. Now it is showing the edit form with user details. Now when I click save, it is saving the data and the page refreshes and re-loads in the pop-up. What I need is to close the pop-up upon saving. Helpful if anyone can suggest a solution..?

Answer (score 0):

Mostly after page refersh pop-up may not displaying automatically untill & unless its not put on `onLoad event`. but if you facing this problem, then you can set `style` with `display:none` after successful saving the data.

Thanks.